# Can we avoid mapping all the fields to entity class in springdata for elasticsearch, as I have more than 100 field in the json document?

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, microservices, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am implementing a spring-boot microservice for elasticsearch (es) operations using springdata APIs. My documents that are indexed in es are huge with multiple fields (more than 100).

Is there a way to avoid defining/hardcoding all the fields in the entity class for elasticsearch object in java?

My sample patient JSON could be like:

```
{
  "key_1":"value_1",
  "key_2":"value_2",
  "key_3":"value_3",
         .
         .
         .  

  "key_n":"value_n"
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse json without knowning the keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25680929/parse-json-without-knowning-the-keys)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, no it doesn't solve the issue. The problem here is there needs to be an entity class which represents the document in the elasticsearch index. I am looking for a way to avoid it and still perform CRUD operations for es from my microservice.

Comment: how do you need to search in these documents?

Comment: based on the key, mostly using a "match" query of elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

If you can go for a slightly different form to store your data in Elastcisearch, you can go use the following:

Define your entity as follows (I am omitting getter/setter for brevity):

```
@Document(indexName = "innerdata")
public class InnerDataEntity {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Object)
    private List<InnerData> innerData;
    
    static class InnerData {
        @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
        private String key;
        private String value;

    }
}
```

Using this with a Spring Data Elasticsearch Repository will create the index with the following mappings:

```
{
  "innerdata": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "ignore_above": 256,
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          },
          "type": "text"
        },
        "innerData": {
          "properties": {
            "key": {
              "type": "text"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `value` property is automapped, if you need to search them as well, add the `FieldType.Text`.

You can then search with the key value by defining a repository like this:

```
public interface InnerDataRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<InnerDataEntity, String> {
    SearchHits<InnerDataEntity> searchByInnerData_Key(String key);
}
```

and use it for example in a controller:

```
@GetMapping("/{key}")
public SearchHits<InnerDataEntity> allByKey(@PathVariable String key) {

    return repository.searchByInnerData_Key(key);
}
```

The data that is stored in Elasticsearch looks like this:

```
{
  "hits": {
    "hits": [
      {
        "_id": "1",
        "_index": "innerdata",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "id": "1",
          "innerData": [
            {
              "key": "key-1",
              "value": "value-1"
            },
            {
              "key": "key-2",
              "value": "value-2"
            }
          ]
        },
        "_type": "_doc"
      },
      {
        "_id": "2",
        "_index": "innerdata",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "id": "2",
          "innerData": [
            {
              "key": "key-1",
              "value": "value-1"
            },
            {
              "key": "key-3",
              "value": "value-3"
            }
          ]
        },
        "_type": "_doc"
      }
    ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea of restructuring the json in elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you  "@P.J.Meisch", for pointing me the right direction!

I resolved the issue by performing document (json) restructuring, that will be indexed in elasticsearch.
It was done by keeping the anonymised patient id at the root level and rest of the patient details in a sub json. Below is my Model class.

```
@Component
@Document(indexName = "manual_patients") // name must be lower case
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString(callSuper=true, includeFieldNames=true)
// @NoArgsConstructor
public class ManualPatient {

    @Id
    private String _id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    @ApiModelProperty(position = 0)
    private String patientId;

    private Map patientDetails;

    public ManualPatient(){}

    public ManualPatient( String patientId, Map patientDetails) {
        this.patientId = patientId;
        this.patientDetails = patientDetails;
    }
}
```