# Spring Data Elasticsearch dynamic mapping. Map property as key-value?

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

There is an elastic index that the application generates. The mapping of an object into an index is described, and then there was a need to create fields in the index dynamically (i.e., fields that are not in the described mapping).
Mapping example:

```java
@Document (indexName = "product", createIndex = true)
public class Product {
    @Id
    @Field (name = "id", type = FieldType.Long)
    private Long id;

    @Field (name = "name", type = FieldType.Text)
    private String name;
}
```

It is necessary to add fields to it when writing a document to the index?

```
count_mag1 = 5, 
count_mag2 = 6,
... 
count_magN = 5
```

That is, fields that are not described in the mapping and their numbers are dynamic.

As I understand it, in this case, I only need to leave the described Entity and save entities through the Spring data repositories?
Ideally, of course, I would like to add a property to the Entity with a collection value of the form:

```java
@Document (indexName = "product", createIndex = true)
public class Product {
  @Id
  @Field (name = "id", type = FieldType.Long)
  private Long id;

  @Field (name = "name", type = FieldType.Text)
  private String name;

  private Map <String, Long> counts;
}
```

and at the stage of forming a request in elastic, iterate over this map and create elements with such a key value, and ignore this itself. Maybe there is such an opportunity and I don't notice it?

**Update:**

No, unfortunately it doesn't suit me. In the above question, the data is nested in the innerData field and now I am achieving the same result by specifying the following option in the Entity:
`private Map<String, Long> counts;`
My goal is to end up with something like this:

```
"_index": "infos",
"_type": "_doc",
"_id": "123456",
"_version": 1,
"_seq_no": 6919,
"_primary_term": 1,
"_routing": "4",
"found": true,
"_source": {
    {
        "id": 123,
        "name": "test",
        "count_wh_1": 123,
        "count_wh_2": 1234,
        "count_wh_3": 1235,
        .....
        "count_wh_N": 123,
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to search for entries with certain keys?Have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63780364/can-we-avoid-mapping-all-the-fields-to-entity-class-in-springdata-for-elasticsea/63800201#63800201

Comment: @P.J.Meisch, No, unfortunately it doesn't suit me.
I've added an update to the original question with clarification.

Comment: this mapping is not possible with Spring Data Elasticsearch. And keep in mind that Elasticsearch would create a dynamic property mapping for every of these _count_sh_N_ properties. Elasticsearch limits the number of fields in a document to 1000, so you might run into trouble there as well.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch Thank you very much for your reply. Very sorry,.

Answer (score 0):

may be you can try **Custom Conversions**

```java
 @Bean
  @Override
  public ElasticsearchCustomConversions elasticsearchCustomConversions() {
    return new ElasticsearchCustomConversions(
      Arrays.asList(new AddressToMap(), new MapToAddress()));       
  }

  @WritingConverter                                                 
  static class AddressToMap implements Converter<Address, Map<String, Object>> {

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> convert(Address source) {

      LinkedHashMap<String, Object> target = new LinkedHashMap<>();
      target.put("ciudad", source.getCity());
      // ...

      return target;
    }
  }

  @ReadingConverter                                                 
  static class MapToAddress implements Converter<Map<String, Object>, Address> {

    @Override
    public Address convert(Map<String, Object> source) {

      // ...
      return address;
    }
  }
```